# I don't want to write login and logout code again and again, is it possible to write code at one place and call that place in my whole test?

Tags: cypress

```
describe('Cypress Test', () => {
    before(async () => {});

    // it 1
    it('Navigating to login screen', () => {
        cy.visit('localhost:4280/auth/login');
    });

    // it 2
    it('should accept registered credentials', () => {
        cy.get("input[id="username"]").clear().type("admin");
        cy.get(story47Obj.btnLoginSubmit).click();
        cy.get("input[id="password"]").clear().type("admin");
        cy.get("button[id="submit"]").click();
    });

    // it 3
    it('URL must include dashboard', () => {
    cy.url({timeout: 5000}).should('include', '/dashboard')
    });

    // it 4
    it('Test: should logout it', () => {
    cy.get("button[id="logout"]").should('be.visible').click();
    });
});
```

I have to write these 4 **it** again and again, because i want many time login and logout in my test.
But the issue is i have to write this code again and again, how can i embed this code in a function, and call that function to optimize my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your custom "helper" functions in `cypress/support/index.js`

In your case it'll be following code:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("it1", => {
    cy.visit('localhost:4280/auth/login');
});

Cypress.Commands.add("it2", => {
    cy.get("input[id="username"]").clear().type("admin");
    cy.get(story47Obj.btnLoginSubmit).click();
    cy.get("input[id="password"]").clear().type("admin");
    cy.get("button[id="submit"]").click();
});

Cypress.Commands.add("it3", => {
    cy.url({timeout: 5000}).should('include', '/dashboard')
});

Cypress.Commands.add("it4", => {
    cy.get("button[id="logout"]").should('be.visible').click();
});
```

You can then call these methods like:

```js
    cy.it1();
    cy.it2();
    cy.it3();
    cy.it4();
```

---

**Note to your login approach:**
In general, it's better to login programmatically rather then clicking the buttons. Consider sending a login request directly from cypress, rather than always clicking the buttons to login.